# How to pass parameters to read method for Kendo ui listview with SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, signalr, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI ListView with SignalR to my ASP.Net MVC application as below code sample:

CSHTML code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<TestApp.Models.testViewModel>()
        .Name("LVTest")
        .TagName("div")
        .ClientTemplateId("templateTest")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .SignalR()
            .Transport(tr => tr
                    .Promise("hubStart")
                    .Hub("testHub")
                    .Client(c => c.Read("test_Read"))
                    .Server(s => s.Read("test_Read"))
                    )
           .Schema(schema => schema 
                  .Model(m => { m.Id(p => p.Id); })
                  )
           )
        )
```

HUB code:

```
public IEnumerable<TestViewModel> Test_Read(string CurrencyId)
    {
        var queryResult = TestRepository.Test_Read(CurrencyId);
        return queryResult;
    }
```

I would like to pass the CurrencyId as a parameter to the read method here. I can achieve this by using the .Data method of datasource for Ajax binding but need to achieve this by suing SignalR. How can I pass the parameter to the read method herre?

Comment: You see this? http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-pass-parameter-to-grid-signalr-read-data-source-method

Comment: I have seen this forum and checked the demo given in this but it is for filtering out the data after the read method fetch the data. In my case I need to pass the specific value to the read method and based on the parameter passed to the read method, data will be fetched and displayed to the listview control.

Comment: Have you come to a solution for this?

Comment: @werdsackjon Finally fond the solution. I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution using ParameterMap as below:

CSHTML code

```
<script>
function customParameterMap(data, operation) {
    var selectedEmpId = $("#ddlEmp").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    if (operation === "read") {
        data.selectedEmpId = selectedEmpId;
    }
    return data;
}
```

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<TestApp.Models.testViewModel>()
    .Name("LVTest")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("templateTest")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .SignalR()
        .Transport(tr => tr
                .ParameterMap("customParameterMap")
                .Promise("hubStart")
                .Hub("testHub")
                .Client(c => c.Read("test_Read"))
                .Server(s => s.Read("test_Read"))
                )
       .Schema(schema => schema 
              .Model(m => { m.Id(p => p.Id); })
              )
       )
    )
```

HUB code

```
public class ReadRequestData
{
    public string selectedEmpId { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<TestViewModel> Test_Read(ReadRequestData data)
{
    string EmpId = data.selectedEmpId;
    var queryResult = TestRepository.Test_Read(EmpId);
    return queryResult;
}
```